# How to define the a

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```js
module.exports.get = function (data) {

  const _data = require("./data/Users.json");

  if (_data.find(a => a.uid === data)) {

    return a.name

  } else return "User"

}
```

I want to return a.name but it says that a is not defined

Comment: Assign it to a variable before the `if` check: `var found = _data.find(a => a.uid === data); if(found) return found.name else return "User"`

Comment: You could also use: `return _data.find(a => a.uid === data)?.name ?? "User"` and remove the `if` block entirely

Answer (score 0):

The [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)  method of array returns the first element that matches the provided condition; if no element is found, `undefined` is then returned. Thus:

```js
const a = _data.find(user => user.uid === data)

if (a) {
  return a.name
} else {
  return "User"
}
```

It is recommended to give arguments and variables good names for better readability and maintainability. The following code can do the same thing, but is usually considered easier to understand:

```js
module.exports.get = function (uid) {
  const users = require("./data/Users.json");
  const user = users.find(user => user.uid === uid);
  return user?.name ?? "User";
}
```

The single question mark and double question marks are [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) respectively, which is not a must. Using if/else is perfectly fine in this case.